# SQLAlchemy - Cyclic data - CircularDependencyError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy and I have next to no SQL or SQLAlchemy experience.

The data I'm trying to represent is not a simple hierarchical tree.

There are two data types: Records and Targets. They are related like so:

- Records have one or more Targets.
- Targets have zero of more Records.
- Targets may share Records
- Records may share Targets.

Base is the declarative base from SQLAlchemy.

This is the code I've tried, however, I get the `CircularDependencyError` but the data IS circular.

Code:

```
class Record(Model, Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "records"
    NAME          = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    TITLE         = Column(Text)
    COMPANY       = Column(Text)
    LOCATION      = Column(Text)
    DATE          = Column(Text)
    BLURB         = Column(Text)
    BULLET        = Column(Text)
    URL           = Column(Text)

    targets_id  = Column(Text, ForeignKey("targets.NAME"))
    targets = relationship("Target", back_populates = "records")

class Target(Model, Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "targets"
    NAME          = Column(Text, primary_key = True)
    MODULE        = Column(Text)
    URL           = Column(Text)
    JOB_URL       = Column(Text)
    COMPANY       = Column(Text)

    records_id  = Column(String, ForeignKey("records.NAME"))
    records = relationship("Record", back_populates = "targets")
```

I've looked at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many , however it seems like a bit of a hack. Is there another approach to represent this in SQLAlchemy that preserves this circular relationship?

**EDIT:**

Some example data:

```
RA:
    NAME     = "RA"
    TITLE    = ...
    COMPANY  = ...
    LOCATION = ...
    DATE     = ...
    BLURB    = ...
    BULLET   = ...
    URL      = ...
    TARGETS  = [ TA, TD, ... ]

RB:
    NAME     = "RB"
    TITLE    = ...
    COMPANY  = ...
    LOCATION = ...
    DATE     = ...
    BLURB    = ...
    BULLET   = ...
    URL      = ...
    TARGETS  = [ TB, TD, ... ]

TA:
    NAME    = "TA"
    MODULE  = ...
    URL     = ...
    JOB_URL = ...
    COMPANY = ...
    RECORDS = [ RA, RB, ... ]
```

Comment: Can you show some sample table rows. Say for a target `TA` and records `RA` and `RB`

Comment: The table doesn't exist yet. I'm trying to create the table using SQLALchemy. The source data is in CSVs.

Comment: This looks like a fit case for many to many. Any reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: The documentation linked to in the question does cover Many-to-Many, however, it involves an indirect and obtuse implementation; I wanted to be more direct.

Comment: Unfortunately if you are representing many-to-many relationships in a relational database (like MySQL or Postgres) you can only do it via an intermediate table i.e. you will need `record_target` table in your database. Since you are new to SQL I suggest you should read about various relationships and their usage (one-to-one, one-to-many many-to-many) in a general sense (not related to sqlalchemy) and once you get the crux should look to SQLAlchemy manual for solving the specific problem you have

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feared that would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [RedBaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533524/redbaron) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317869/sqlalchemy-cyclic-data-circulardependencyerror#comment33920038_22317869) , SQL requires an intermediate table for circular data.

As I am using the declarative base, I wanted a solution which was consistent; unlike those presented in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many).

The documentation refers to the intermediate table as an Association Object.

The syntax to use such objects is subjectively ugly, particularly when appending related records (but this is a consequence of SQL's own limitation). So I used an [Association Proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects); however the examples in the documentation are confusing to a novice.

This solution is based on the one found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973678/associate-objects-in-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy).

Code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Record(Model, Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "records"
    NAME          = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    TITLE         = Column(Text)
    COMPANY       = Column(Text)
    LOCATION      = Column(Text)
    DATE          = Column(Text)
    BLURB         = Column(Text)
    BULLET        = Column(Text)
    URL           = Column(Text)

    targets       = association_proxy("target_records", "target", creator = lambda target: Target_Record(target = target))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s: %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.NAME or "Unamed")

class Target(Model, Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "targets"
    NAME          = Column(Text, primary_key = True)
    MODULE        = Column(Text)
    URL           = Column(Text)
    JOB_URL       = Column(Text)
    COMPANY       = Column(Text)

    records       = association_proxy("target_records", "record", creator = lambda record: Target_Record(record = record))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s: %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.NAME or "Unamed")

class Target_Record(Model, Base):
    __tablename__ = "target_records"
    target_id     = Column(Text  , ForeignKey("targets.NAME"), primary_key = True)
    record_id     = Column(String, ForeignKey("records.NAME"), primary_key = True)
    target        = relationship(Target, backref = backref("target_records"))
    record        = relationship(Record, backref = backref("target_records"))
```